# WPF - Content of two user controls bound to same instance of control

Tags: c#, wpf, listboxitem

I have a wpf/c# application.;
I have a list box and according to the selected item I display a certain view.
I have one view for all and different values displayed.
The view looks like this:

```
<UserControl.Content>
    <Binding Path="DisplayControl" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
</UserControl.Content>
```

The DisplayControl is a UserControl in the View Model of the list box item (I know it's not the best but that can't change for now).
It is shared between all listbox items.
The last listbox item (the last one that the DisplayControl set property was called for) is the one that shows the view when it is clicked - all the others show blank.

What is the problem? They are bound the same way, why does the last one only display the control and how do I fix this?

Comment: I do not understand whay is your goal.
Do you want to change the content related to the selecteItem from the ListBox?

Comment: Yes. But it must be a binding to a view and not a view model. I understand this is not the correct way but it cannot be changed at the moment

Comment: Can you please show us the ViewModel binded to your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try something like this:

ViewModel.cs

```
public TypeModel
{
    private string _label;
    public string Label{ MVVM stuff}

    private UserControl _userControl;
    UserControl UserControl { MVVM stuff }
}

public class toto
{
private ObservableCollection<TypeModel> _list;
public ObservableCollection<TypeModel> List
{
get{return this._list;}
set { set value and notifyPropertyChanged }
}

private TypeModel _selectedItem;
public TypeModel SelectedItem
{
get{ return this._selectedItem;}
set { set value and NotifyPropertyChanged }
}

}
```

In your view.xaml

```
<listbox normal binding to List + selectedItem binding>
<ContentControl Binding={SelectedItem.UserControl} >
```

This is only pseudo code, try to stick to your existing code like this :)

Btw: @Ed Plunkett  is right.

Comment: This is solid, but I could wish you had put the pseudocode bits like `MVVM Stuff` in /**/ comments, for clarity.

Comment: I did that very quickly from the office. I will edit it later :)

Comment: Thanks. It would be a good solution for this situation. I ended up changing the DisplayControl property to null for the previous selected item each time the selected item was changed, that way only one list box item at a time would have the control binded. I'll mark this as the answer since I think it's better than my solution which was only chosen because of constraints.

Answer (score 4):

A control in WPF can have only one parent at a time. In fact, it can only be in one PLACE at one time. You are giving `DisplayControl` two different parents in rapid succession. The second one is where it ends up.

What are you actually trying to *accomplish* here? In program spec terms, not "I'm trying to pound a nail with a live dog because the birthday cake didn't work as a shovel". Do you want the *content* of `DisplayControl` to be shown in two different places at once? That's workable.

Anyway, first order of business is not to store any UserControls in your viewmodel. That can and must change. You're putting some kind of content in the UserControl, right? That's what it's there for, right? So have the *content* in your viewmodel, and display it in one or more UserControls in the view using a template.

The more time you waste trying to get this plumber's nightmare to work, the worse it'll get. The [Sunk Cost Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_costs) is not your friend. But for most people, there's only one way to learn that.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. Unfortunately it's not my decision to change the entire view and view model, otherwise I would. Thanks for your answer.